# Python differs with results in list with integers versus strings

Tags: python

I was trying to create a reverse rail-fence cipher, when I stumbled upon an error!
Here is my code:

```
n=len(cipher)
strings=[]
for r in range(3,4):
    lis=[[0 for i in range(n)] for i in range(r)]
    x,y=0,0
    for c in cipher:
        try:
            lis[x][y]=c
        except:
            for i in lis:
                print(i)
            print(x,y)
            break
        y+=2*r-3
        print(y)
        if y>=n:
            y-=n
            x+=1
            print(x,y)
    x,y,z=0,0,1
    s=""
    for i in range(n):
        try:
            if(lis[x][y]==0):
                print(r,n)
            s+=lis[x][y]
        except:
            for i in lis:
                print(i)
            print(x,y,c)
            break
        y+=1
        if x==0:
            z=1
        elif x==r-1:
            z=0
        if z==1:
            x+=1
        else:
            x-=1
    strings.append(s)
return strings
```

I added in several try/except statements to determine the error. Later though, I found that if I changed a single line, line 4, to read as

```
lis=[['.' for i in range(n)] for i in range(r)]
```

The code worked flawlessly (as in didn't create any errors - it still didn't produce the right result)!

The only differences between the codes is this single line. I am using Python 37 on Windows 10.

Why does the one code work where the other doesn't?

**EDIT:** My input cipher is "Js s!ae saeoemiwm", which was encoded using three "rails" in a rail-fence cipher.

**EDIT 2:** I have a working version to reverse this cipher, but the point of this question is why does changing the 0's to '.' make a difference in any way?

Comment: *"...stumbled upon an error!"*. Don't you think posting that error would help you some way?

Comment: `for r in range(3,4):` just runs one time with `r=3`, so why write it as a `for` loop?

Comment: I set the for loop from (3,4) for debugging purposes (as I had already encoded something using my rail_fence encoder, and an r value of 3 should have decoded it properly).
I have a working version of the code, and can share it if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is this line:

```
s+=lis[x][y]
```

`s` is a string, so you can only concatenate other strings to it. If `lis[x][y]` contains `0`, that's a number, not a string, so you can't concatenate it.

If you change it to:

```
s += str(lis[x][y])
```

then it will work with either initial value.